# Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'. IONIC 3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

```
BUILD FAILED in 4s
11 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 10 up-to-date
(node:5457) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:  Error: /Users/lucaszimmermann/Desktop/www/****/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 4s
      at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/lucaszimmermann/Desktop/www/****/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
      at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
  (node:5457) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
  (node:5457) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: What cordova android version are you on?

Comment: cordova --version
8.0.0 and jdk1.8.0_171.

Comment: **Please try the help, I can not solve this !!!**

Comment: cordova-android@7.0.0